# How do I run a binary before compiling and running tests?

Tags: testing, rust, code-generation, functional-testing, rust-cargo

My crate is a code generator that generates a parser.

I would like to write tests that run a generated parser and compare its result to the expected result. This requires that I run my crate's binary prior to the tests to get the parser's code, compile that code, and **then** run the tests.

How can I do that with Cargo?

This is very similar to [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1581), which unfortunately is not solved.

Comment: Probably just use the workaround suggested in the issue you linked - write these tests in a separate crate. Not ideal obviously.